# How to convert object to JSON in symfony2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I am using this:

```
    $users = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->getallUsers($search);
    $response = new Response(json_encode($users));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
```

Users are multiple entities not single result.

But I am getting this:

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

I want something like:

```
[ { label: $user.getName(), value: $user.getId() }, ... ]
```

How can i do that?

**EDIT:** I also tried `json_encode($users->toArray())` then I get this error:

> Call to a member function `toArray()` on a non-object

Comment: Which version of symfony do you use?

Answer (score 6):

You need to have a way to serialize your objects, you can't expect `json_encode` to magically guess which fields are allowed to be encoded.

A good bundle I recommend for this task is [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle).
Make sure you read through documentation carefully before using it!

End result will probably look like this:

> ```
> $users = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->getallUsers($search);
> $response = new Response($container->get('serializer')->serialize($users, 'json'));
> ```

Comment: I already jave JMSSerializerBundle installed but i get this error `You have requested a non-existent service "serializer".` how can i declrae the service for JMS

Comment: it is there in jms vendor and its latest version

Comment: You have to register the bundle in your app/AppKernel.php

Comment: You can try : 
$serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
$response = new Response($serializer->serialize($users, 'json'));

Comment: @Inoryy you miss the `$this` before `container`

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{ your_variable|raw }}`

Sorry for late

Comment: Well this is the best easy method, but it is not automatic and requires implementing `__toString()` function in a class, which returns `json_serialize(array(..))` product.